# Cannot logout from IMAP server (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, imap

Using Ruby I'm writing a daemon which synchronizes mails from an IMAP server. I have multiple accounts which I log into one after another and download unread messages. However I'm unable to reuse the existing connection to the IMAP server.

Here's a rough example of what I want to do:

```
require 'net/imap'

imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.example.com')

imap.login('login@example.com', 'R2D2C3PO')
imap.select('INBOX')

# interacting with the server, like fetching the messages etc.
# for example:
puts imap.fetch(3, "BODYSTRUCTURE")

# now I want to log out of the account and log in with another
imap.logout

imap.login('anotherlogin@example.com', 'R2D2C3PO')
imap.select('INBOX')    

# again - interacting with the server
puts imap.fetch(3, "BODYSTRUCTURE")

imap.disconnect
```

However an exception is raised when calling the `logout` method:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:110:in `sleep': No live threads left. Deadlock? (fatal)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:110:in `wait'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:110:in `wait'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/imap.rb:1166:in `get_tagged_response'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/imap.rb:1225:in `block in send_command'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/imap.rb:1207:in `send_command'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/imap.rb:435:in `login'
        from test.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

I'm completely baffled by a threading exception, since the daemon is only single-threaded. Under the hood the process is hang on the conditional variable while waiting for the server response. Why it wasn't a problem when calling previous methods (`LOGIN`, `SELECT` and other commands) and it becomes a problem when sending the `LOGOUT` command?

---

### **Edit:**

I somehow completely missed the fact, that the `LOGOUT` command renders the connection to the IMAP server no longer usable (as @HolgerJust points out). Although my idea to reuse the connection has failed miserably, the main point still stands: the exception is raised when sending the `LOGOUT` command, which at this point is still a legitimate action and should not cause any trouble.

Comment: Your issue appears to be in 'login', not 'logout'.

Comment: I highly doubt it's a problem with the `LOGIN` command, since after the first login I'm able to download all the mails without any hassle.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood you completely. Yes, it was indeed the problem with the `LOGIN` command after all. Somehow I was convinced that the problem was with the `LOGOUT` command all along. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have logged out from an IMAP session, you have to create a new connection to execute any further commands. After a LOGOUT, the connection is not allowed to be further re-used.

To quote from [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.1.3):

> The LOGOUT command informs the server that the client is done with
> the connection.  The server MUST send a BYE untagged response
> before the (tagged) OK response, and then close the network
> connection.

In Ruby code, this effectvely means that after you have called `logout` on your `imap` object, you can't do anything useful with it anymore. Instead, create a new connection by creating a new `imap` object.

Comment: Ah, now this little fact that I missed turned my idea into rubble! However, it still doesn't answer my question - the exception is still being raised on the `LOGOUT` command, when I'm actually done with the connection and want to clean the playground. On a side note: calling the `imap.disconnect` method instead does work, but it feels like a dirty little hack. I'd prefer to inform the server I'm done with the connection with the `LOGOUT` command, like the RFC standard states and the way it's intended.

Comment: The exception is being raised on the second `login` call, not on `logout` as shown in your stack trace. It might be your line numbers are a bit off though. As for your other remarks, please see my edit.

Comment: What an embarrassment. Yes, you are right. I misread the stack trace and got mislead by the line number. Now everything fits. However, I don't really understand your new comment on the connection, that the IMAP object would automatically create a new connection when sending a new command. Each time I call the `login` method after disconnecting, I get the exception that the stream is closed. It does not get reconnected in any way. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Meh, turns out I miss-read the documentation. Sorry for that. Indeed, there is no way to use the existing `imap` object after logging out or disconnecting. Once the socket is closed, the only way to re-open it is to create a new `imap` object. As such, the original version of my answer still stands.